# Jersey Endpoint+OSGi Dependency, Keeping Track

Tags: java, rest, osgi, jersey-2.0, apache-felix

I have a Jersey endpoint which uses a custom OSGi Service `ExceptionManager` Service.

```
@Path("service")
public class ServiceFacade {
    private volatile ExceptionManager exceptionManager;

    public ServiceFacade() {
        BundleContext bC = FrameworkUtil.getBundle(ServiceFacade.class).getBundleContext();
        ServiceReference<ExceptionManager> sR = bC.getServiceReference(ExceptionManager.class);
        if (sR != null)
            this.exceptionManager = bC.getService(sR);
    }

    @GET
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response sayHello() {
        try {
            if (exceptionManager == null)
                return Response.status(Status.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE).build();

            // Do some work...
        } catch (Exception e) {
           exceptionManager.handle(e);
        }
    }
}
```

This Jersey class is added to the Jersey Application as a simple class, that means that every time a user hits this endpoint, a new instance of this class is created to handle the request. As you can see, the class contains a constructor which initializes the `ExceptionManager` Service. My question is, isn't there a simplified way of retrieving the service without going to `BundleContext`?

I have seen `DependencyManager`, but this bundle seems to only add the dependencies to the class (`ServiceFacade` in this case) during the Activation process, but that dependency resolution is too early this has to be done during run-time, every time an instance is created. Bellow is an approximation with `DependencyManager` but is not a solution for this:

```
public class Activator extends DependencyActivatorBase {
    @Override
    public void init(BundleContext bundleContext, DependencyManager dependencyManager) throws Exception {
       dependencyManager.add(createComponent()
                  .setImplementation(ServiceFacade.class)
                  .add(createServiceDependency()
                               .setService(ExceptionManager.class)
                               .setRequired(true));
    }
}
```

Thanks.-

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain the reference to an OSGi service without accessing to BundleContext by using Declarative Services. [A tutorial can be found here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/OSGiServices/article.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can make the endpoint a [singleton resource](https://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/jaxrs-resources.html#d0e2563). This way you can let the dependency manager create a single instance and inject services and then add that instance to the Jersey application.

There are a few limitations, like Jersey's field or constructor injection does not work. You also have to be careful about concurrency when using fields of the resource.